# A quick way to mock a REST service, for Android/GSon usage?

Tags: android, rest, gson

We tried WCF and it is fairly complex, and it returns nulls in the JSON, which GSon chokes on.

Is there another quick and dirty way to mock a REST service, for Android/GSon usage ?

Comment: Wow, WCF returns null!  I had no idea.

Comment: Was this issue resolved?  Note that Gson handles deserializing with null in the JSON just fine, assuming the JSON is otherwise valid.

Comment: Some date format issues et.al. but GSon <-> WCF communication solved. 
However, the real question was regarding finding a easy/Q&D way to create a REST service, to use while developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to test my rest client on different server responses, ended up with writing this one: https://github.com/mkotsur/restito.